# Unable to use SK maps in Android studio

Tags: android, skmaps

I am trying to use SK maps SDK for Android, but I am facing some problems. I have followed as guided on this website :http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android for integrating SDK in Android but still I am making mistake somewhere it seems. The problem is: As soon I launch the app, the first activity is correctly starting but as soon as SK maps library is initialised and the Map activity is created, the app crashes without showing any error. 
Here is my Initialization code:

```
public class Map_initialization extends AppCompatActivity implements SKMapsInitializationListener {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);
    SKMaps.getInstance().initializeSKMaps(getApplication(),this);
}

@Override
public void onLibraryInitialized(boolean b) {  ///once maps initialized then go to map activity
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Here is my Map Activity Code: Here map is created.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SKMapSurfaceListener {

double lat;
double lng;
float zoom_level=0;
String Location="19.875692,75.353020";
// get the annotation object
SKAnnotation new_loc = new SKAnnotation(10); //marker which can be visible on map


/**
 * Surface view for displaying the map
 */
private SKMapSurfaceView mapView;

/**
 * the view that holds the map view
 */
SKMapViewHolder mapHolder;

// get the callout view object from the map holder
SKCalloutView mapPopup = mapHolder.getCalloutView();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mapHolder = (SKMapViewHolder) findViewById(R.id.map_surface_holder);
}
 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    SKMaps.getInstance().destroySKMaps();
}

public void Show_Location()
{

    lat=Double.valueOf(Location.substring(0,9));//extracting latitude
    lng=Double.valueOf(Location.substring(10,Location.length()));//extracting longitude
    zoom_level=16;
    new_loc.setAnnotationType(SKAnnotation.SK_ANNOTATION_TYPE_BLUE);
    new_loc.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(lat,lng));
    mapView.animateToZoomLevel(zoom_level);
    mapView.animateToLocation(new SKCoordinate(lat,lng),1000);
    mapView.addAnnotation(new_loc, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_PIN_DROP);//adding marker

    // set the callout view’s background color
    mapPopup.setViewColor(Color.argb(255, 200, 200, 255));
    mapPopup.showAtLocation(new SKCoordinate(lat,lng),true);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mapHolder.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mapHolder.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActionPan() {
    zoom_level--;
    mapView.setZoom(zoom_level);
}

@Override
public void onActionZoom() {
    zoom_level++;
    mapView.setZoom(zoom_level);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(SKMapViewHolder skMapViewHolder) { //on map surface created
    mapView = mapHolder.getMapSurfaceView();
    mapView.getMapSettings().setMapPoiIconsShown(true);
    mapView.getMapSettings().setMapPanningEnabled(true);
    mapView.getMapSettings().setMapZoomingEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void onMapRegionChanged(SKCoordinateRegion skCoordinateRegion) {

}

@Override
public void onMapRegionChangeStarted(SKCoordinateRegion skCoordinateRegion) {

}

@Override
public void onMapRegionChangeEnded(SKCoordinateRegion skCoordinateRegion) {

}

@Override
public void onDoubleTap(SKScreenPoint skScreenPoint) {

}

@Override
public void onSingleTap(SKScreenPoint skScreenPoint) {

}

@Override
public void onRotateMap() {

}

@Override
public void onLongPress(SKScreenPoint skScreenPoint) {

}

@Override
public void onInternetConnectionNeeded() {

}

@Override
public void onMapActionDown(SKScreenPoint skScreenPoint) {

}

@Override
public void onMapActionUp(SKScreenPoint skScreenPoint) {

}

@Override
public void onPOIClusterSelected(SKPOICluster skpoiCluster) {

}

@Override
public void onMapPOISelected(SKMapPOI skMapPOI) {

}

@Override
public void onAnnotationSelected(SKAnnotation skAnnotation) {

}

@Override
public void onCustomPOISelected(SKMapCustomPOI skMapCustomPOI) {

}

@Override
public void onCompassSelected() {

}

@Override
public void onCurrentPositionSelected() {

}

@Override
public void onObjectSelected(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onInternationalisationCalled(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onBoundingBoxImageRendered(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onGLInitializationError(String s) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ERROR:"+s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onScreenshotReady(Bitmap bitmap) {

}
}
```

Here is my gradle for app:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
}
}
//apply plugin: 'java'
repositories {
maven {
    url "http://developer.skobbler.com/maven/"
}
}

configurations {
skobblersdk
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.ahirrao.gps"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),       
    'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
skobblersdk "com.skobbler.ngx:SKMaps:3.0.0"
compile files('libs/SKMaps.jar')
}

def assetsPath = "$projectDir/src/main/assets"
def libsPath = "$projectDir/libs"
def jniLibsPath = "$projectDir/src/main/jniLibs"

task installSKMaps << {
copy {
    from configurations.skobblersdk
    into "$buildDir/skobblersdk-down"
    rename { String fileName -> 'skobblersdkres.zip' }
}
copy {
    from zipTree("$buildDir/skobblersdk-down/skobblersdkres.zip")
    into "$buildDir/skobblersdk-down"
}
delete("$jniLibsPath",
        "$assetsPath/SKMaps.zip",
        "$libsPath/SKMaps.jar")
copy {
    from "${buildDir}/skobblersdk-down/jniLibs"
    into "$jniLibsPath"
}
copy {
    from "${buildDir}/skobblersdk-down/"
    into "$assetsPath"
}
copy {
    from "${buildDir}/skobblersdk-down/SKMaps.jar"
    into "$libsPath"
}
delete("$buildDir/skobblersdk-down")
delete(configurations.skobblersdk)
}
```

This is my Layout for map:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKMapViewHolder
    android:id="@+id/map_surface_holder"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

And on the above website of Skobbler, they have given the code by using JAVA plugin in gradle but I am not able to use it as it is not compatible with android plugin.

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

 Process: com.example.ahirrao.gps, PID: 541

 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity   
ComponentInfo{com.example.ahirrao.gps/com.example.ahirrao.gps.MainActivity}: 
 java.lang.NullPointerException at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264)
at       
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.ahirrao.gps.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:53)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1215)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: No answer yet? maybe @Ando will give nice answer, as he helped many in skmaps regard.

Comment: on the skobbler website you can find a demo project for Android Studio - are you sure you don't have any error log? For example where do you set the API key?

Comment: @Ando Hi, I have got demo project I am successfully running it. And I am setting API key in manifest using METADATA tags.And what about the gradle file?I believe problem is in this, as on website it is said to use java plugin but I am not able to use it and hence map may not have installed correctly. How can I use java plugin? regarding errors, I will post the logcat.

Comment: you should be able to bypass gradle altogether by manually adding the required files (.so, .jar, SKMaps.zip). I believe that the gradle script file is not working as the pom file uploaded on the server has a 3.0 termination and it should be 3.0.0 (type-o mistake but stopping the script from correctly working)

Comment: so shall I remove all the code in gradle regarding adding SKmaps etc? because manually I am adding those.

Comment: yes - please look at the gradle scripts in the demo project

Comment: @Ando so shall I remove all the code in gradle regarding adding SKmaps etc? because manually I am adding those.And how where to add SKMaps-docs.jar file? In demo project it is added to sdk-tools module but I am using single module. And on skobbler website, it is given to modify <JAVADOC> but that modification gets deleted as soon as Gradle build is done.So what can be done to it?

Comment: @Ando Thank you for your support. Till now I cleared that "Unable to instantiate Activity" error but now I am getting Null pointer exception at `mapView.animatetozoom` how there can be null? I have initialized zoom_level variable to zero.

Comment: Is your mapView pointer not null?

Comment: @Ando null? I am not sure. I am following as directed by Skobber's website.I even tried removing zoom option, then exception occured at `mapView.addAnnotation`! I tried adding annotaion view instead of just annotation, but with same errors. Without adding annotation maps opens and works perfectly, but adding annotation causes errors.

Comment: @Ando I have tried checking mapView for nul,though map is visible!l but it shows always null.And hence Annotation is not showing on map. I even tried using a boolean and initialized it as false and change it in onSurfaceCreated() but it is not called it seems, as that boolean variable is always false.And hence method for adding annotation is never called.

Answer (score 3):

I figured the error. I was making mistake. Maybe it will help somebody.

I was calling all visual elements before map Surface is created, this caused errors like Null pointer exceptions and cashed the app.So the procedure is to test `mapView`for null or set a boolean in `onSurfaceCreated`method and test for whether map view is created or not, then draw annotations,etc on map.Also in `onCreate` we have to set MapSurface listener on calling `onSurfaceCreated`which I haven't done and hence caused errors like no annotations were drawn.